# Async Requests Using Android Clean Architecture

Tags: android, asynchronous, repository-pattern, clean-architecture

I want to run async two requests using clean architecture in android, I've searched many sites but I didn't find what I'm looking for.
could any help me with how to do this!.

I will explain what I am doing in one request:

1- Repo has a dependency on (remote - local) data sources.

2- UseCase to execute repo.

3- Map the response to ViewModel.

My question is how to do this in two links run in parallel Using Clean Architecture (usecase - repo and Flow)?

Comment: Do it in two threads (or coroutines, either way).  That's kind of obvious, so is there something else you're trying to ask?

Comment: @GabeSechan yes i know i can do it with coroutines, but I'm asking about how to do this in the clean architecture way, using the usecase and repo because from my experience in clean arch every request should have its own repo and usecase, so how to run two requests in async ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use coroutines with async builder to run multiple calls in parallel like below

```
suspend fun fetchTwoDocs() =        // called on any Dispatcher (any thread, possibly Main)
coroutineScope {
    val deferreds = listOf(     // fetch two docs at the same time
        async { fetchDoc(1) },  // async returns a result for the first doc
        async { fetchDoc(2) }   // async returns a result for the second doc
    )
    deferreds.awaitAll()        // use awaitAll to wait for both network requests
}
```

here fetchDoc(1) and fetchDoc(2) will run in parallel

reference: https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-adv#parallel

Comment: Yes i know this solution but i'm asking how to do this in a clean arch using usecase and repo